# A question about weighted forward unilateral shift operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

We define

$$
B(x_{1}, x_{2},...)=(0, \frac{x_{1}}{2}, \frac{x_{2}}{3},...,x_{n})\in  l^{2}(N),
$$

How could be shown that that $B$ is a quasinilpotent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) By induction show that
$$
B^n(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=\left(0,0,\ldots,0,\frac{x_1}{2\cdot\ldots\cdot (n+1)},\ldots,\frac{x_k}{(k+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+k)},\ldots\right)
$$

2) Then derive that
$$
\Vert B^n\Vert\leq\frac{1}{(n+1)!}
$$

3) Using Stirling's formula show that spectral radius 
$$
r(B)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Vert B^n\Vert^{1/n}=0
$$

4) Recall that spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of any bounded operator $A$ satisfies
$$
\varnothing\neq\sigma(A)\subset\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:|\lambda|\leq r(A)\}
$$
hence $\sigma(B)=\{0\}$. This means by definition that $B$ is quasinilpotent.

Comment: Thanks Norbert, but i suppose that it is "$k+1$"(not "$k-1$") in your first step.

Comment: yes you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Note that an operator $B$ is quasi-nilpotent iff
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \|B^n\|^{1/n} = 0
$$
Now note that
$$
B^n(x) = (0,0,0,\ldots, 0, \frac{x_1}{(n+1)!}, \frac{2x_2}{(n+2)!}, \frac{6x_3}{(n+3)!}, \ldots )
$$
Now,
$$
\frac{j!}{(n+j)!} = \frac{1}{(j+1)(j+2)\ldots (n+j)} \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}
$$
and hence
$$
\|B^n\| = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \Rightarrow \|B^n\|^{1/n} = \frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}
$$
But $e^x \geq \frac{x^n}{n!}$, so by plugging in $x=n$, one sees that
$$
\sqrt[n]{n!} \geq \left ( \frac{n}{e}\right )
$$
Putting all this in, one gets
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \|B^n\|^{1/n} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}\frac{1}{(1+1/n)^{1/n}}\frac{e}{n} = 0
$$

Comment: I am sorry, i think there is something wrong in your answer. But thanks for your help all the same.

Comment: @Belle-tiantian : Care to explain that?